# My Dovecot server stopped authorizing clients

Tags: dovecot, thunderbird

I have seen answers to some similar queries on the web, but none of them have helped me fix this issue.

I installed an instance of Thunderbird directly on the server, and it can pick up mail from the server.  Other clients off the server can pick up mail from the server, and the other Thunderbird clients can pick up mail from other servers.

I have been running Dovecot as an IMAP server on one of my Debian Linux servers for many years.  Around the beginning of January, it quit allowing Thunderbird clients to download emails.  I have tried everything I of which I can think and looked at everything I know, but I can't figure out what is wrong.  I think perhaps if I can force the Thunderbird clients to allow a refresh of the server certificate for the IMAP system, perhaps it would help, but when  I try to obtain the certificate from the system, Thunderbird says it cannot obtain it.  Does anyone know how I should proceed?

doveconf -n:

```
# 2.3.19.1 (9b53102964): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.5.19 (4eae2f79)
# OS: Linux 6.1.0-10-amd64 x86_64 Debian 12.1 
# Hostname: RAID-Server
debug_log_path = /var/log/dovecot/mail.bug
info_log_path = /var/log/dovecot/mail.inf
log_path = /var/log/dovecot/mail.err
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=~/mail/inbox
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
protocols = " imap"
ssl_cert = </etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
ssl_client_ca_dir = /etc/ssl/certs
ssl_dh = # hidden, use -P to show it
ssl_key = # hidden, use -P to show it
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
protocol imap {
  mail_max_userip_connections = 50
}
```

```
root@Backup:~# openssl s_client -connect 192.168.1.50:993 -tls1_2
CONNECTED(00000003)
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = RAID-Server.att.net
   i:CN = RAID-Server.att.net
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Oct 30 01:53:54 2019 GMT; NotAfter: Oct 27 01:53:54 2029 GMT
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<removed>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = RAID-Server.att.net
issuer=CN = RAID-Server.att.net
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 1388 bytes and written 281 bytes
Verification error: self-signed certificate
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: AE20DEEF2FD8CC7F3881B59D51CBCB23B436E92DF06F87124F7E8A760010FFAB
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 2FC5D8CF5E6C8D77A9BA3FB659F026E6E83328A1BF98E9EF12736DC9B3778BD2260DBB1588CE0E731BF21479DC1D81A0
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 7200 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - af bc 75 17 7e 2e 44 35-67 52 2e b4 72 7c 18 49   ..u.~.D5gR..r|.I
    0010 - 5e 63 02 50 39 b7 47 d6-de 02 2b e9 ff e9 6b fa   ^c.P9.G...+...k.
    0020 - 5f 27 f2 85 a0 a6 63 47-58 65 be f6 54 f7 96 1e   _'....cGXe..T...
    0030 - e2 b5 d4 af c7 be 06 8b-8f 15 5e 65 55 27 46 61   ..........^eU'Fa
    0040 - d7 e4 75 08 27 47 97 67-a6 37 bc 67 49 17 24 ab   ..u.'G.g.7.gI.$.
    0050 - 78 6f c8 ba af 3e e6 b0-b4 f3 96 9f c3 0a e5 bc   xo...>..........
    0060 - 70 30 c6 9e e2 2d 68 37-a1 68 2c dd dc b8 12 87   p0...-h7.h,.....
    0070 - 9a 60 fd 1f be 25 8a 10-19 46 83 47 ea 7d 8c 16   .`...%...F.G.}..
    0080 - d8 b8 18 ea 38 12 95 23-96 ac 13 82 e2 04 16 6c   ....8..#.......l
    0090 - c7 77 bd 80 59 91 2d a2-28 f7 75 f7 ce 5a 7e 1f   .w..Y.-.(.u..Z~.

    Start Time: 1708484596
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 18 (self-signed certificate)
    Extended master secret: yes
---
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE LITERAL+ AUTH=PLAIN] Dovecot (Debian) ready.
```

[image: Arrempt to get certificate in Thunderbird]

[Thunderbird settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55GbS.jpg)

Comment: Look into your logs.

Comment: I have.  There is nothing diagnostic there.  It just says things like, "Feb 18 02:43:28 imap-login: Info: Disconnected: Connection closed: read(size=429) failed: Connection reset by peer (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=192.168.1.121, lip=192.168.1.50, TLS: read(size=429) failed: Connection reset by peer, session=<NI+V+KMRPvTAqAF5>", over and over when I try to pick up mail.  There are tons of these sort of errors listed on the web, but none of fixes apply.

Comment: Your client is dropping connection, check its log.

Comment: What error message does Thunderbird give? Is the certificate really valid?

Comment: Thunderbird does not give any errors, and there is nothing in its log.  The only time it does is when I change the authorization from SSL/TLS to something else or change the password method.  Given that and the fact I am unable to cause it to fail, I am not sure how I am supposed to tell if it is valid or not.

Comment: Simple stupid question: have you tried restarting Dovecot?

Comment: Yes, of course I have.  Not only Dovecot, but the server itself, all the clients, and all the machines running the clients.  Why has someone discounted this query?  It is a serious query, and none of these clients have been able to pick up their mail for nearly two months.

Comment: i could just guess, but what is the business related question or issue, that involves business related hardware in here?

Comment: Use `openssl s_client -connect` to test the TLS connection, could be expired certs.

Comment: It looks OK, to me.  See above.  The evidence suggests to me the issue is primarily with Thunderbird but only in conjunction with the Dovecot server.

Comment: What kind of cert do you use? Le? Self signed?

Comment: Look with `tcpdump` if it is really the client sending RST packets. Check if there is an antivirus intercepting mail traffic on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have have a config file like this for logging

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker-mailserver/docker-mailserver/master/target/dovecot/10-logging.conf

```
##
## Log destination.
##

# Log file to use for error messages. "syslog" logs to syslog,
# /dev/stderr logs to stderr.
log_path = syslog

# Log file to use for informational messages. Defaults to log_path.
#info_log_path =
# Log file to use for debug messages. Defaults to info_log_path.
#debug_log_path =

# Syslog facility to use if you're logging to syslog. Usually if you don't
# want to use "mail", you'll use local0..local7. Also other standard
# facilities are supported.
syslog_facility = mail

##
## Logging verbosity and debugging.
##

# Log unsuccessful authentication attempts and the reasons why they failed.
auth_verbose = yes

# In case of password mismatches, log the attempted password. Valid values are
# no, plain and sha1. sha1 can be useful for detecting brute force password
# attempts vs. user simply trying the same password over and over again.
# You can also truncate the value to n chars by appending ":n" (e.g. sha1:6).
auth_verbose_passwords = sha1:6

# Even more verbose logging for debugging purposes. Shows for example SQL
# queries.
#auth_debug = no

# In case of password mismatches, log the passwords and used scheme so the
# problem can be debugged. Enabling this also enables auth_debug.
#auth_debug_passwords = no

# Enable mail process debugging. This can help you figure out why Dovecot
# isn't finding your mails.
#mail_debug = no

# Show protocol level SSL errors.
verbose_ssl = yes

# mail_log plugin provides more event logging for mail processes.
plugin {
  # Events to log. Also available: flag_change append
  #mail_log_events = delete undelete expunge copy mailbox_delete mailbox_rename
  # Available fields: uid, box, msgid, from, subject, size, vsize, flags
  # size and vsize are available only for expunge and copy events.
  #mail_log_fields = uid box msgid size
}

##
## Log formatting.
##

# Prefix for each line written to log file. % codes are in strftime(3)
# format.
#log_timestamp = "%b %d %H:%M:%S "

# Space-separated list of elements we want to log. The elements which have
# a non-empty variable value are joined together to form a comma-separated
# string.
#login_log_format_elements = user=<%u> method=%m rip=%r lip=%l mpid=%e %c

# Login log format. %s contains login_log_format_elements string, %$ contains
# the data we want to log.
#login_log_format = %$: %s

# Log prefix for mail processes. See doc/wiki/Variables.txt for list of
# possible variables you can use.
#mail_log_prefix = "%s(%u): "

# Format to use for logging mail deliveries. You can use variables:
#  %$ - Delivery status message (e.g. "saved to INBOX")
#  %m - Message-ID
#  %s - Subject
#  %f - From address
#  %p - Physical size
#  %w - Virtual size
#deliver_log_format = msgid=%m: %$
```

---

Another thing can you try this and see what happens

```
sudo apt-get install mailutils
imap4d your_imap_server_address
```